# instantiate object ONLY from other class in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, class, instantiation

I have 2 classes A and B (in VB.NET).

I want the only way to create an object of B class was by using a mehtod of A.

**Examples:**

**You could do:**

```
Dim objectA as new A
Dim objectB as B = objectA.getAobject()
```

**BUT you couldn´t do:**

```
Dim objectB as new B
```

Thanks!

Edit: in "You could do" section I wanna mean "Dim objectB as B = objectA.getAobject()"

Comment: Why not just go Dim objectB  = A.getAobject() ? You'll have to turn strict off though, which may not be good.

Comment: The only way to achieve this is to place class `A` inside class `B` and let class `B` have a private constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a private constructor in B:

```
Private Sub New()

End Sub
```

If there are no public constructors, this will block you from writing code like this anywhere but within B itself:

```
Dim objectB as new B
```

However, this *requires* you to write code like that somewhere in B, or you won't be able to ever create an instance of B *anywhere*. Typically a Shared method is the place to do this:

```
Friend Shared Function Create() As B
    '...
    Return New B
End Function
```

Note the `Friend` access modifier. Now, if you have an assembly (class library project) containing only A and B, only code inside that assembly (only A and B) will be able to use that function. Add to that a method in A that looks like this:

```
Public Shared Function getObject() As B
   Return B.Create()
End Function
```

And we've met all your stated objectives. Code that references this assembly will be able to do this:

```
Dim objectB as B = A.getAobject()
```

But will not be able to do either of these:

```
Dim objectB as new B
Dim objectB As B = B.Create()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Project of type **Class Library** and add code similar to this for Class A and Class B

```
Public Class A
    Public Function getObject() As B
        Return New B()
    End Function
End Class

Public Class B

    Protected Friend Sub New()
        Console.WriteLine("Constructor B called")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now the Constructor of Class B could only be called from inside code present in this project not from other assemblies

In your main project you need to add a reference to this new project and Imports its namespace.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim a1 = New A()
        ' Dim b1 = New B() 'This will not compile at all'
        Dim b2 = a1.getObject()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Of course now you have to distribute two files instead of one....

The key for this to work is the different assembly and the keyword [Protected Friend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/08w05ey2.aspx) applied to the constructor of class B

Answer (score 0):

You could just check in the constructor of B, if your calling class is of type A

```
Class B 
    Sub New ()
        ' get parent frame and calling method
        Dim frame As StackFrame = new StackFrame( 1, True )
        Dim method As MethodBase = frame.GetMethod()

        ' for debug purposes
        Dim methodName As String = method.DeclaringType.Name & "->" & method.Name
        Console.WriteLine(methodName)

        ' throw exception
        If (method.DeclaringType.Equals(typeof(A)) = False) {
            throw new Exception("Not called from class A!!")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```